# Magento Update: There is no Mage_All_Latest in Magento Connect?

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, upgrade

I want to update my Magento 1.9.1.1 over Magento connect. BUT there are only the installed extensions listed. No Magento entries order even `Mage_All_Latest`. 
So I followed some tips from this forum and tried to install `Mage_All_Latest`. but every time i got some errors that the files are exciting.

so how can i install `Mage_All_Latest` (and/or update my Magento)? 
i hope i don't have to build my whole site new.

[image]

Comment: can you send the error screenshot

Comment: As you see: no magento files... so I tried to install Mage_All_Lastest with this code: http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Mage_All_Latest

Then, after Magento worked, I got the following log:

Checking dependencies of packages Already installed: community/Interface_Frontend_Rwd_Default 1.9.3.4, skipping Already installed: community/Mage_Locale_en_US 1.9.3.4, skipping Already installed: community/Lib_Unserialize 1.9.3.4, skipping Already installed: community/Lib_IDNA2 1.9.3.4, skipping

Comment: CONNECT ERROR: Package 'Mage_All_Latest' is invalid '.\pkginfo\Mage_All_Latest.txt' already exists Package 'Interface_Adminhtml_Default' is invalid './app/design\adminhtml\default\default\etc\theme.xml' already exists Package 'Interface_Frontend_Default' is invalid './app/design\frontend\default\default\etc\theme.xml' already exists Package 'Interface_Install_Default' is invalid './app/design\install\default\default\etc\theme.xml' already exists    ....,.and so on

Comment: so you are not getting magento packages right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Please follow the below steps:**

1. Copy the var/package folder from default magento1.9.1.1 and paste in your magento var/
2. Delete pkginfo/Mage_All_Latest.txt folder
3. After this if you still not getting upgrade options, please follow the below steps:

> Go To downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php

**Find line:**

> $uriModified = $this->getModifiedUri($uri, $https);

**Before this line write:**

> $https = false;

**Comment this line:**

> $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');

Comment: please try this and let me know the progress thanks

Comment: Yes, this will useful.

Comment: hi, sorry, i wasn't on the pc... first, thanks for your tips...what do you mean with default magento? do you mean the "fresh"/"naked" magento before any theme and so on?

Comment: went great if have the options now...

Comment: but sadly it conflicts now:

Comment: Checking dependencies of packages
Installing package community/Phoenix_Moneybookers 1.9.3.4
Package community/Phoenix_Moneybookers 1.9.3.4 installed successfully
Already installed: community/Mage_Locale_en_US 1.9.3.4, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_Unserialize 1.9.3.4, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_IDNA2 1.9.3.4, skipping
Package upgraded:
 community Phoenix_Moneybookers 1.9.3.4

CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.3.4 conflicts with: community/Interface_Frontend_Base_Default 1.9.1.1,

Comment: Package community/Lib_Js_Mage 1.9.3.4 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.1.1
Package community/Lib_Phpseclib 1.9.3.4 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.1.1
Package community/Lib_Mage 1.9.3.4 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.1.1

Comment: did you Delete pkginfo/Mage_All_Latest.txt folder before upgrade start?

Comment: yes, it was deleted. :-(

Comment: tried it today again, but there appears everytime the same error (new module 1.9.3.4 conflicts with 1.9.1.1 [CONNECT ERROR]) => e.g CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Lib_Credis 1.9.3.4 conflicts with: community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.9.1.1

Comment: IT WORKS!!! i found the mistake: only Mage_All_Lastest was allready at 1.9.3.4 so i uninstalled it to 1.9.1.1 again and started the update again... now I am an 1.9.3.4! thanks for your help Raghu! :-)

Comment: the only thing now: some CMS-pages (e.g. business terms) are empty now - do you know what there is going on? (I use MageSetup)

Comment: can you send me the frontend link

Comment: sadly is at the moment on my localhost with wampserver :-(

Comment: ok np..no cms page will be effected when upgrade is done.. please remove cache and session once and check

Comment: ...I read somthing like the blocks of magesetup need after a magento update extra permissions in system=>permissions=>blocks, did you hear from that? how can i set this permissions?

Comment: already all block types will be there in permissions.

Comment: If your  custom block type is not present at that location you have to add new block and save as allowed thats it

Comment: i add: cms/business_terms => Allowed  but nothing changed

Comment: actually do you want to change/create cms page or any block types?

Comment: ...it works!! i just filled in "cms/block" and all is fine! all missing content is shown now! Raghu, thank you so much for your help!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my magento connect (without the Mage_All_Lastest):

[image: Magento Connect Overview]

As you see: no magento files... so I tried to install Mage_All_Lastest with this code: http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Mage_All_Latest

Then, after Magento worked, I got the following log:

Checking dependencies of packages
Already installed: community/Interface_Frontend_Rwd_Default 1.9.3.4, skipping
Already installed: community/Mage_Locale_en_US 1.9.3.4, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_Unserialize 1.9.3.4, skipping
Already installed: community/Lib_IDNA2 1.9.3.4, skipping

> CONNECT ERROR: Package 'Mage_All_Latest' is invalid
>   '.\pkginfo\Mage_All_Latest.txt' already exists Package
>   'Interface_Adminhtml_Default' is invalid
>   './app/design\adminhtml\default\default\etc\theme.xml' already exists
>   Package 'Interface_Frontend_Default' is invalid
>   './app/design\frontend\default\default\etc\theme.xml' already exists
>   Package 'Interface_Install_Default' is invalid
>   './app/design\install\default\default\etc\theme.xml' already exists
>   Package 'Mage_Downloader' is invalid '.\downloader\js\prototype.js'
>   already exists Package 'Mage_Centinel' is invalid
>   './app/code/core\Mage\Centinel\Block\Adminhtml\Validation\Form.php'
>   already exists Package 'Interface_Frontend_Base_Default' is invalid
>   './app/design\frontend\base\default\etc\theme.xml' already exists
>   Package 'Phoenix_Moneybookers' is invalid
>   './app/code/community\Phoenix\Moneybookers\Block\Form.php' already
>   exists Package 'Mage_Compiler' is invalid
>   './app/code/core\Mage\Compiler\Block\Process.php' already exists
>   Package 'Magento_Mobile' is invalid
>   './app/code/core\Mage\XmlConnect\Block\Adminhtml\Admin\Application\Edit\Form.php'
>   already exists Package 'Lib_Cm' is invalid
>   './lib\Cm\Cache\Backend\Redis.php' already exists Package
>   'Cm_RedisSession' is invalid
>   './app/code/community\Cm\RedisSession\Model\Session.php' already
>   exists Package 'Mage_Core_Adminhtml' is invalid
>   './app/code/core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Abstract.php' already exists
>   Package 'Mage_Core_Modules' is invalid
>   './app/code/core\Mage\Admin\Helper\Data.php' already exists Package
>   'Lib_Js_Ext' is invalid '.\js\extjs\css\README.txt' already exists
>   Package 'Lib_LinLibertineFont' is invalid
>   './lib\LinLibertineFont\Bugs' already exists Package 'Lib_Js_TinyMCE'
>   is invalid '.\js\tiny_mce\classes\AddOnManager.js' already exists
>   Package 'Lib_Varien' is invalid './lib\Varien\Autoload.php' already
>   exists Package 'Lib_Google_Checkout' is invalid Empty package contents
>   section Package 'Lib_Js_Calendar' is invalid
>   '.\js\calendar\calendar-blue.css' already exists Package 'Lib_Js_Mage'
>   is invalid '.\js\lib\FABridge.js' already exists Package
>   'Lib_Phpseclib' is invalid './lib\phpseclib\Crypt\AES.php' already
>   exists Package 'Lib_Mage' is invalid './lib\Mage\Archive\Abstract.php'
>   already exists Package 'Lib_Magento' is invalid
>   './lib\Magento\Autoload\ClassMap.php' already exists Package
>   'Lib_Credis' is invalid './lib\Credis\Client.php' already exists
>   Package 'Lib_Pelago' is invalid './lib\Pelago\Emogrifier.php' already
>   exists Package 'Lib_ZF' is invalid
>   './lib\Zend\Acl\Assert\Interface.php' already exists Package
>   'Lib_Js_Prototype' is invalid '.\js\prototype\debug.js' already exists
>   Package 'Lib_ZF_Locale' is invalid
>   './lib\Zend\Locale\Data\Translation.php' already exists

Comment: Hello and Welcome to StackExchange. This is not an answer. Please add your question details to the question itself by editing it.